# Distributable zip webserver

Tags: scala, gradle, build.gradle, scalatra

I have a webserver written in Scala using scalatra (embedded jetty) and building with Gradle.
I am trying to create a distributable which will contain the structure bin/lib/etc.

The code below creates what I want when run `gradle distZip` but I am struggling to find what is needed to compile and place the runnable jar in the bin folder.
What steps am I missing?

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'webServer'
        contents {
            into('bin') {
                // What goes here???
            }
            into('lib') {
                from configurations.runtime
            }
            into('etc') {
                from ('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to copy the jar file that is produced by the `jar` task, added by the scala plugin. The jar task, of [type Jar](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html), has an `archivePath` property containing the name of the archive file produced by the task. So what you want is

```
from jar.archivePath
```